# ASP.NET MVC Web publishing does not copy excel file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-deployment, web-deployment-project

My project has Help folder which is located within web project AND in which we kept some template excel files.

When we do "Web Publishing", these files does not get copied on the server. If we change the extension to xml from xslx then they get copied.

Can you please suggest something to change the publishing scheme/method?

Have a nice weekend!!!

Answer (score 1):

Set the "Copy to Output Directory" flag in the File Properties

Answer (score 1):

Select the file in Solution Explorer, and in the properties window change Build Action to Content.
For more background information on how files are selected for publishing, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#why_dont_all_files_get_deployed